# error while file uploading using enctype=multipart/form-data , the error is the file bring uploaded is not multipart

Tags: java, html, jsp

when i try to upload files it given an error that the file being uploaded is not multipart .

I have given the links to the files in the links . 
thanks in advance . [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9GhSdaQWjMkNEZDOHlkZlNXNVk)
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9GhSdaQWjMkRlppQldhdzExZHc)

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

why does your stylesheet have the multipart tag???

This should be on the form like this:

```
<form  action = "RegisterController" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
```